# Editable ComboBox with custom objects rewrites items on dropdown list

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, dropdown

I have a filterable `ComboBox` filled with custom `Subjekt` objects.

Filtered list is populated from database using `SubjektDAO.searchSubjectsByName()` method.

Added listener to the editor of the `ComboBox` and used `cbNazivKupca.show()` method to automatically open dropdown list (which is populated and showing ) as I start typing.

Filtering works ok (as I type the list is filtered), but when I select item from list (lets say "abraham") , change its value in `ComboBox` textfield (lets say to "abrah") and click somewhere else (so `ComboBox` looses focus) the "abrah" value appears in dropdown list and I loose the original value.

I need to disable entering new values in list (i could do this by setting combobox not editable) but i have a big amount to scroll through.

Also if i click on button to display items in list and click on first one in line it is populated in text box , but if i click on second or some next i need to click him twice (this only happens once).

I dont know how to solve this , im new to JavaFX and learning.

Please help.

```
try {

    final FilteredList<Subjekt> filteredItems = new FilteredList<>(SubjektDAO.searchSubjectsByName(), p -> true);

    cbNazivKupca.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {


        cbNazivKupca.show();

        final TextField editor = cbNazivKupca.getEditor();
        final Subjekt selected = cbNazivKupca.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();


    /*
    This needs run on the GUI thread to avoid the error described
    here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081700.
    */

        Platform.runLater(() -> {

        /*
        If the no item in the list is selected or the selected item
        isn't equal to the current input, we refilter the list.
        */
            if (selected == null || !selected.toString().equals(editor.getText())) {
                filteredItems.setPredicate(item -> {
                    cbNazivKupca.setVisibleRowCount(10);
                    // We return true for any items that contains the
                    // same letters as the input. We use toUpperCase to
                    // avoid case sensitivity.
                    if (item.getSubjekt_naziv().toUpperCase().contains(newValue.toUpperCase())) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    cbNazivKupca.setItems(filteredItems);
} catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


//  rendering of the list of values in ComboBox drop down.
cbNazivKupca.setCellFactory((comboBox) -> {
    return new ListCell<Subjekt>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Subjekt subjekt, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(subjekt, empty);

            if (subjekt == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(subjekt.getSubjekt_naziv());
            }
        }
    };
});

cbNazivKupca.setConverter(new StringConverter<Subjekt>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Subjekt subjekt) {
        if (subjekt == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return subjekt.getSubjekt_naziv();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Subjekt fromString(String productString)
    {
        if(cbNazivKupca.getValue() != null)
        {
            ((Subjekt)cbNazivKupca.getValue()).setSubjekt_naziv(productString);

            return (Subjekt)cbNazivKupca.getValue();
        }
        return null;

    }

});
```

**EDITED**: I have narrowed down the source of problem to the cbNazivKupca.setConverter fromString method, but im stuck i need to check if cbNazivKupca.getValue() is present in dropdown list.

**EDITED**: I came to similar solution too, but the thing that baffles me is :
when i click on dropdown button and the items are listed if i click the first on list it gets copied to editable part but if i click any other the editor gets cursor and is empty and if i click it again all is good, this only happens once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fromString` method of your converter is invalid. The purpose of [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/StringConverter.html#fromString-java.lang.String-) is to return an object with the type of the generic parameter type of the `StringConverter`, nothing else:

> Converts the string provided into an object defined by the specific
>   converter. Format of the string and type of the resulting object is
>   defined by the specific converter.

So in this method you should not get the selected item and even worse you should not modify the selected item, actually this is the reason to have the items in your dropdown list modified.

The `fromString` method is used when you type into the editor of the `ComboBox` then press enter to find out which item should be selected (the item what the method returns) based on the string you have typed into the editor (input parameter of the method).

What you should do is to get the corresposing `Subject` instance from the items of the `ComboBox`, like:

```
@Override
public Subjekt  fromString(String productString) {
    return cbNazivKupca.getItems().stream().filter(item -> productString.equals(item.getSubjekt_naziv())).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

This will return the first element from the items in the `ComboBox` which `subjekt_naziv` member is the same as the specified `String` or null if matching is not possible.